# WinXP/MFC: Bluetooth enumeration: reset device list?

Tags: mfc, windows-xp, bluetooth

Im looking at a group of Bluetooth devices that I need to work with. They have a known bank of MAC addresses so I can pick them out of the enumerated list. Im running into problems getting the system to provide me with a current list.

```
BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO radioInfo;
radioInfo.dwSize = sizeof(radioInfo);
HRESULT hr = ::BluetoothGetRadioInfo(hRadio, &radioInfo);

BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS deviceSearchParams;
memset(&deviceSearchParams, 0, sizeof(deviceSearchParams));
deviceSearchParams.dwSize = sizeof(deviceSearchParams);
deviceSearchParams.fReturnAuthenticated = false;
deviceSearchParams.fReturnRemembered = false;
deviceSearchParams.fReturnUnknown = true;
deviceSearchParams.fReturnConnected = false;
deviceSearchParams.hRadio = hRadio;

HANDLE hDeviceFind = ::BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&deviceSearchParams, &deviceInfo);
```

I loop through the device list and pick out the recognized units.

It seems that I have to rerun the control panel applet in order to refresh the discoverable devices or else I get what appears to be a 'remembered' list (rather than the actual list of devices that are local, non-paired and turned on).

Suggestions?

Using XP/VC2008/MFC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW: If you want to reset the list, use this code:

```
WORD wVersionRequested = 0x202;
WSADATA m_data;

if ( ::WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &m_data) == S_OK )
{
   WSAQUERYSET querySet;

   memset(&querySet, 0, sizeof(querySet));

   querySet.dwSize = sizeof(querySet);

   querySet.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;

   HANDLE hLookup;
   DWORD flags = LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_FLUSHCACHE |      LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RES_SERVICE;

   int nResult = WSALookupServiceBegin(&querySet, flags, &hLookup);
   WSALookupServiceEnd(hLookup);
   WSACleanup();

   if( nResult != S_OK ) return FALSE; 
   else return TRUE;
}

return FALSE;
```